# Обособление вставки (опять)

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`Я считаю(,) – это просто моё мнение, если что, – что не надо говорить детям «не издеваться» над языком, делая их какими-то-с недетьми.`

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148655/discussion-on-question-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Я вам дал другой ответ. На этот раз не буду рекомендовать переносить или не переносить галочку, а дам вам выбрать самим, как считаете вы. Прочитайте, говорите свое мнение, согласны или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Я считаю – **это просто моё мнение, если что**, – что не надо говорить детям «не издеваться» над языком, делая их какими-то-с недетьми.*

Вставка относится к первой части, вторая запятая "перенесенная" (относится к основной структуре предложения).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148676/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Запятая не перенесённая, поскольку запятая нужна перед "что", а не после "считаю" (слово "считаю" не требует запятую).

Answer (score 0):

Я всë же считаю, что вставку рациональнее будет отнести ко второй части:

*Я считаю, – это просто моё мнение, если что, – что не надо говорить детям «не издеваться» над языком, делая их какими-то-с недетьми*.

Поясню. Сначала уберем оборот *если что*:

*Я считаю, – это просто моё мнение – что не надо говорить детям «не издеваться» над языком, делая их какими-то-с недетьми*.

Запятая перед первым тире обособляет придаточное, к которому лучше булет отнести вставку. Поэтому отделяем от первой части, присоединяя ко второй. А если добавить оборот *если что*, то запятые получатся с двух сторон:

*Я считаю, – это просто моё мнение, если что, – что не надо говорить детям «не издеваться» над языком, делая их какими-то-с недетьми*.

---

Вывод: лучше всего поставить запятую.

Comment: Симметричная вставка?  А зачем?  Вставка  относится к первой части.  Перенос структурной запятой.

Comment: @Sharon Я всë же считаю, что лучше ко второй. Это ПРОСТО МНЕНИЕ (без злости). Да и почему не отнести к следующей? Можно вроде.

Comment: По семантике явно к первой, вот я и интересуюсь.  И симметрия вам нравится?

Comment: @Sharon Я обособил не с целью симметрии, то есть ре брал запятые из воздуха (не намек). Каждая запятая на своем основании. Перед первым тире запятая обособляет придаточное, к которому я отнес вставку, а второе тире закрывает оборот _если что_.